# jQuery Parent Sibling selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, show-hide

I have a HTML document like below:

```
<td>
  <div class="commentLink">
    <a href="javascript:ShowBox()">Show</a>
  </div>
  <div class="hiddenBox">
    <!-- Hidden content  -->
  </div>
</td>
```

The div element with `class="hiddenBox"` is hidden by default. On clicking the "Show" link, I want to show the hidden div. I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
function ShowBox() {
  $(function(){
    $(this).parent().siblings(".hiddenBox").show();
  });
}
```

The class `hiddenBox` occurs multiple times in my document, but I want only the sibling to show.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The problem is that `this` in your function won't be the `<a>` element. You can change your inline handler like this to fix it:

```
<a href="#" onclick="ShowBox.call(this); return false;">Show</a>
```

Ah just noticed, additionally you'll need to reference the `this` outside of the ready handler.

```
function ShowBox() {
   var that = this;
   $(function(){
       $( that ).parent().siblings(".hiddenBox").show();
   });
}
```

I assume you've set it up this way in case someone clicks the link before the DOM is loaded.

Comment: @K.R.: Works for me. [Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/wH2H7/). Note that I updated my answer about 20 minutes ago. Also make sure your `ShowBox()` function is *not* located inside another function.

Comment: Yes. It does work. Thank you so much for your help. Could you explain your soluion. I don't understand what you mean by "The problem is that this in your function won't be the <a> element". If it doesn't reference the <a> element, does it reference the parent div ?

Comment: @K.R.: In JavaScript, the value of `this` in a function is determined by *how* that function is called. When you do `href="javascript:ShowBox()"`, the value of `this` in your function will be the `Window` object, and there's no way to set it to anything other. If you did `onclick="ShowBox()"`, the value of `this` is still the `Window`, but you have the option of using the `.call` method, which is simply a way of *manually* setting the value of `this` in the function you're calling. So what we did, is we passed `this` as the first argument to `.call()`. Why? Because within the inline...

Comment: ...`onclick` handler, `this` will be a reference to your element. So doing `ShowBox.call( this )` will make `this` in `ShowBox` refer to your element. To test it, change the `onclick` to `onclick = "alert( this.nodeName );"` or `onclick = "alert( this.innerHTML );"`. You'll see that `this` is a reference to your element, and is giving you the name of the tag, or the HTML content of that element you clicked.

Comment: ...We had a similar problem inside your function, because you wrapped your code in yet another function that is being passed as a callback. When jQuery calls that callback, it will set `this` to something else. As such, we stored a reference to the initial value of `this` in a variable called `that`, and referred that variable to run your code against the correct element.

Answer (score 5):

Use closest http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Comment: Even better if you combine that with an element selector.

Answer (score 0):

looks like the following is wrong

remove that function inside and it should work

```
function ShowBox() {
  $(this).parent().siblings(".hiddenBox").show();
}
```

more elegant way of doing is

give some class to href like "test"

```
 <a class="test">Show</a>

$('.test').click(function() {

    $(this).parent().siblings(".hiddenBox").show();
         return false;
});
```

Comment: The function is called `siblings` (note the `s`).